# No module named admin_view_permission, CircleCI?

Tags: python, django

When I run my Django project on CircleCI I get the following error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'admin_view_permission'"

The project runs with no problems locally on my computer. I added the module admin_view_premissions, to settings, from this page: https://github.com/ctxis/django-admin-view-permission

Then I ran "pip install django-admin-view-permission", and it worked fine. The migration also did not have any problems.

Does anyone know why CircleCI is not able to find the module?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I had to write the package in the Pip-file by using: pipenv install django-admin-view-permission